# Shapefile doesn't fit in CartoDB basemap

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system, carto

When I import some shapefiles in CartoDB they don't fit properly at street level, as you can see in the screenshot. In this case, the shp was generated in QGis with CRS EPSG:29193 - SAD69. I have already tried converting to others CRS with no results. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: CartoDB uses WGS84 http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/projections.html but you can reproject on the fly in cartodb

Comment: it looks like a datum problem. In the US the difference between NAD27 and NAD83 looks like this. perhaps your data is not SAD69?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your dataset and:

1. Open the Shapefile with QGIS
2. Set CRS of the layer to "SAD 69 / UTM zone 23 S EPSG 29193"
3. Save layer as Shapefile, with projection "WGS 84 EPSG 4326". After this, we're requested for the datum, choose: "+towgs84=-66..87,4.37,-38.52"

It works! :)